# Does $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} (\Delta u)=0$ imply that $\lim_{\Delta u\to 0} (\Delta x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

- Let $u(x)$ be some differentiable function
- Let $\Delta x=x-c \text{ where c is some constant}$
- Let $\Delta u=u(x)-u(c)$

Is the following statement true?

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} (\Delta u)=0 \iff \lim_{\Delta u\to 0} (\Delta x)=0$$

I interpreted the LHS to mean 'as $\Delta x$ becomes arbitrarily close to $0$, $\Delta u$ also becomes arbitrarily close to $0$'. But my interpretation didn't seem rigorous enough for me to be certain.

Comment: How is $\Delta u$ related to $\Delta x$?

Comment: Is $\Delta u$ a function of $\Delta x$?

Comment: @Tavish Sorry, I was uncertain about how much context was needed for the question to make sense. I'll clarify by editing my question.

Comment: You mention rigour. Are you familiar with the analytical definition of a limit? We say $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ if and only if $\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0:\lvert x-c\rvert<\delta\Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-L\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c$ is constant, if $\Delta x\to0$ then $x\to c$, and since $u(c)$ is also a constant, if $\Delta u\to0$ then $u(x)\to u(c)$.

You are asking if the following are true:

$$\lim_{x\to c}(u(x)-u(c)) = 0 \iff \lim_{u(x)\to u(c)}(x-c)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to c}u(x)=u(c) \iff \lim_{u(x)\to u(c)}x=c$$

Since one limit is looking at the range of $u$ and the other is looking at the domain of $u$, we need to know about the shape of $u$. Is it bijective, for example?

Take $u(x)=\sin x$. Obviously $\sin x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, but it’s possible for $x$ to approach other values as $\sin x\to0$, such as $π$.

Comment: Just to clarify: The statement is, as it’s written, in general, not true.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily true, unless $u(x)$ is one-one. Suppose $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \Delta u=0$ is true. This means as $x\to c$, $\Delta u = u(x)-u(c) =0$

But $$\lim_{\Delta u \to 0} \Delta x =0 \\ \implies \lim_{\Delta u\to 0} (x-c)=0 \\ \implies x\to c\ \\ \text{as} \, \\ u(x) \to u(c)$$

Clearly, this means $u(t) \ne u(c)$ for any $t\ne c$.